# Custom decorator to pass custom data to function in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to create custom decorator that checks current user and run a query for this user to get some data that belongs him and then if has defined data function is called with whole list passed else returns 403 error.
How can i approach this?

Comment: first of all please try to show us what have you tried and your code ?

Comment: Do you need the whole list in your view function?

Comment: @amadousow I'm doing this inside each of my functions.

Comment: @Mahmoud Yes. I want to show something based on these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write decorator like this:

```
# check_data is what the user must have access to
def custom_decorator(check_data):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            user = request.request.user
            # data_list is list of his access
            data_list = []
            if user.is_authenticated:
                pass
                # you can do your query here to check access
            
            if check_data in data_list:
                kwargs['access_list'] = data_list
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            
            # return Http Error here

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Add access_list parameter to your view function:

```
@custom_decorator("something")
def get(self, request, access_list=None):
```

Comment: With a little change this is what i want.